# How Can You Control Which Curly Bracket Links to Which in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class SpawnManagerX : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public GameObject[] ballPrefabs;

    private float spawnLimitXLeft = -22;
    private float spawnLimitXRight = 7;
    private float spawnPosY = 30;

    private float startDelay = 1.0f;

    void Start()
    {
    InvokeRepeating("SpawnRandomBall", startDelay, spawnInterval);
    InvokeRepeating("IntervalRandomiser", startDelay, spawnInterval);
    }

    void SpawnRandomBall()
    {
        
    Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(spawnLimitXLeft, 
    spawnLimitXRight), spawnPosY, 0);

    Instantiate(ballPrefabs[Random.Range(0, 3)], spawnPos, 
    ballPrefabs[Random.Range(0, 3)].transform.rotation);
    }

    void IntervalRandomiser() {
    public int spawnInterval = Random.Range(3, 6);
    }
```

I insert a new line under "**public int spawnInterval = Random.Range(3, 6);**" (second last line) and add a curly bracket to close the IntervalRandomiser method, but the curly brackets closes the class instead. So, I want the bracket to close IntervalRandomiser but it closes the larger class. How could I choose which method or class the bracket closes?

Comment: What do you mean by "connects"? Do you mean autoindent?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For us to help, you should include the code that didn't work, don't just say it in words.

Comment: Hopefully that makes more sense

Comment: bracket pairs can not cross other bracket pairs.  They have to be contained within.  Just add a closing bracket at the bottom to end the class. did you forget the ;

Comment: There is already a bracket to end MonoBehaviour, if you add in one to close IntervalRandomiser it closes MonoBehaviour, even though it has already been closed.